# PHP class extends not giving feedback

Tags: php, class, extend

What I would like to do is chain a few classes together using "extends". It kinda works, but not like I expected it to. So I must be doing something wrong.

From what I gathered, when you extend a class you inherit all of its properties. So with that in mind I like to make my config file available in all classes. To do this I want to extend all classes on an autoLoader class. This seems logical to me, but correct me if I'm wrong.

I have two classes

AutoLoader

```
Class AutoLoader {

    public $oConf = null;

    public function __construct($oConfig) {
        $this->$oConf = $oConfig;
    }

    public function getConf() {
        return $this->$oConf;
    }

}
```

other class

```
Class foo extends AutoLoader {

    public function bar() {
        var_dump($this->getConf());
    }

}
```

My question is, why is the var_dump NULL.

It is strange to me cause this always returns the conf:

```
$autoLoader = new AutoLoader($array);
var_dump($autoLoader->getConf());
```

What am I missing here.

Comment: You `Autoloader` class constructor expecting a param `$oConfig`, which you're not passing.

Comment: Rikesh, put this in an answer. This is correct as you said. Use `$autoLoader = new Autoloader($myGetConfVariableWithValues);` - edit: like in the answers, the `new Autoloader` should also be `new Foo`

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your code; it would have complained about the missing constructor argument.

Comment: Yeah, thats not it. I just forgot to typ it there. Ill edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are extending and inheriting the *class structure*, not the *object instance*.
Just take this code as an example:

```
$foo = new Foo('foo');
$bar = new Foo;
```

Would you expect `$bar` to have access to the argument `'foo'` passed into the first object somehow? No. Extension doesn't change that.

You should be using composition or dependency injection (e.g. pass an autoloader into the constructor of `Foo`). Don't make `Foo` *an* `Autoloader`, *give* it an `Autoloader` if it needs one. When you extend a class, that new class *is* also its parent class. That means it could be used *in place of* the parent class. Anywhere you'd use an `Autoloader` class, you could substitute `Foo` instead. Does that make sense? Is `Foo` *an* `Autoloader`? Does `$foo instanceof Autoloader == true` make any sense? No.

Comment: I'm not understanding this. For me it looks simple: I have a variable, I put something in it, extend the current code (for me extend sounds like extending the code with all parameters included, but againn correct me if I'm wrong), and I request it. So yes, I would expect to use $this on a variable get too. I do like the way you think about autoloaders, but I can't grasp the fact that my variable returns null.

Comment: You don't really show how you instantiate `Foo`... Possibly the problem is just that you use `$this->$oConf` where you should be using `$this->oConf`. The rest of the argument still stands though.

Answer (score 1):

If inheriting class have an own constructor, you are probably not passing the oConfig to the parenting class (Autoloader) in the case.

also, your constructor expects an config.

So you should be doing this in your child constructor if you don't have one:

```
function __construct($oConfig) {
    parent::__construct($oConfig);
    // rest of your constructor code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create instance of `foo` class and give into constructor your config variable:

```
$config = 'My_config';
$foo = new foo($config);
$foo->bar();
```

Will output:
`(string) "My_config"`